# Add UILabel to Custom UICollectionViewCell doesn't appear in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to UICollectionView. I am trying to add Two UILabel to my Custom `UICollectionViewCell` like following.

```
@interface PassCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headerTitle;
```

I have already connected with `UILabel` in `Storyboard`.
However When i set headerTitle in `CellforITemAtIndexPath` , headerTitle `UILabel` doesn't appearing. Only titleLabel can set value.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PassCell *cell = (PassCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"pass" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Test";
    cell.headerTitle.text // That doesn't appear.

    return cell;
}
```

What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: try [cell.contentview addsubview:titlelabel];

Comment: I added UILabel in Storyboard. And i also connected with IBOutLet. But not appearing in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Create uilabel Programmatically in cellforRow.it works definitely.

Comment: give that label some tag value and use that tag here

Comment: Does the label itself appear? Give it a background color in the storyboard to see. It could be that it's off screen because of inappropriate constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your CustomCell prior to cellForRow method, programmatically (in viewDidLoad)

```
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[PassCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"pass"];
```

I'm not quite sure how its done in StoryBoards, but theres nothing wrong in doing it programmatically.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you make a cell in the storyboard, you should not register the class. Only register the class if you're making your cell entirely in code.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your custom class in storyBoard to the collectionView Cell